# Background Image Not Showing On NativeScript Page

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to display a background image on my login page, it is not showing.

I have tried adding the class to the page and my layout. Neither is working.

Is there something in my code that is preventing this for some reason?

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page bgImage" actionBarHidden="true" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <FlexboxLayout class="page">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, auto, auto">
        <StackLayout class="form ">
            <Image class="logo" src="~/images/johnevolve.png" />
            <Label class="header" text="Health Conscious" />

            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <Label text="Username" />
                <TextField class="input" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email"
                    keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false"
                    autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="next" />
                <Label class="hr-light" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <Label text="Password" />
                <TextField id="password" class="input" text="{{ password }}"
                    hint="Password" secure="true" returnKeyType="{{ isLoggingIn ? 'done' : 'next' }}" />
                <Label class="hr-light" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field" visibility="{{ !isLoggingIn ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}">
                <TextField id="confirmPassword" class="input" text="{{ confirmPassword }}"
                    hint="Confirm password" secure="true" returnKeyType="done" />
                <Label class="hr-light" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Button  text="{{ isLoggingIn ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up' }}" tap="{{ submit }}"
                class="btn btn-primary m-t-20" />

            <Label visibility="{{ isLoggingIn ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}"
                text="Forgot your password?" class="login-label" tap="{{ forgotPassword }}" />
        </StackLayout>
       </GridLayout>

        <Label class="login-label sign-up-label" tap="{{ toggleForm }}">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="{{ isLoggingIn ? 'Don’t have an account? ' : 'Back to Login' }}" />
                <Span text="{{ isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up' : '' }}" class="bold" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>


</Page>
```

and my css:

```
.bgImage {

background-image: url("~/images/1-login.png");

}
```

Edit: Here is the page css rule in case you need that:

```
.page {
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Thank you.

**Image In Question:**
[image: background image]

Comment: May I ask where the background gradient in the attached image is coming from? Can you create a minimal Playground sample?

Comment: Hi Manoj, I decided to do this: ```background: linear-gradient(90deg,#96C809, white);``` , so that got me by this problem.  AND THEN I discovered the problem with the above image not showing. It was such a rookie mistake ( I am actually a rookie with NativeScript, however ) - I had placed my images folder outside of my app directory. Ugh!! Both ways work now. Thank you for looking. I follow your posts and answers, and have learned a lot from you, and for that I thank you. I am getting more proficient each day with NS!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is NativeScript 5.x and you are using HMR/Webpack; the issue is most likely WebPack caused. I have a blog article about this on how to disable HMR mode and re-use Legacy mode.

In a nutshell you need to re-enable Legacy mode.
http://fluentreports.com/blog/?p=935

Please note; this is only relevent to NativeScript 5.x; NativeScript 6 (coming out shortly) will probably not let you re-enable legacy mode.

If you find legacy mode does actually fix your issue; please report this issue to the https://github.com/nativescript/NativeScript-Dev-Webpack repo so it can be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

There was the problem with your `FlexboxLayout` . It was taking the 100% height and overlapping the background image with it's content.

You can also try with giving background Image to your FlexboxLayout.

```
<FlexboxLayout class="page bgImage">
```

and in app.css

```
.bgImage{
    /* background-color: green; */
    background-image: url("~/images/1-login.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}
```

I have created a playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=WwyQNC&v=2).